# Store big data in array of Mongo Object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a user system project using Passportjs and MongoDB, which has the following schema:

```
{ username, email, password}
```

Now I want to store user's activities (login, logout, etc.). These data may be relatively big.

I wonder if it's good to store user data in the following schema:

```
{ username, email, password, [act_type, act_time]}
```

Or it's better (performance) creating a new collection with schema {username, act_type, act_time} (like Relational Databases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These data may be relatively big.

An instant code red in terms of embedding. A maximum document size is 16MB and user activities will most likely easily reach past that.

With the query activity you will also receive on the embedded document you will most likely suffer massive fragmentation problems that not even `powerof2sizes` can help with.

I would recommend splitting this data out into another collection considering only these two points (I am sure there are more).